# Questions about capitalizing words in titles

Tags: capitalization, headline-case

I've got quite a few questions about capitalizing words in titles. I don't know if it's proper to include many questions in one topic, but I couldn't find anything of the sort when I gave the rules a glance. I've been studying how words work in titles and I'd like to think I know most things, but there are a few cases that I can't wrap my head around, as I can't find any specific information on them myself.

EDIT: I've trimmed the amount of questions down from seven to three after checking out some suggestions. The suspected duplicate article helped me out a great bit, and the title case converter was a great help. However, I haven't found a straightforward explanation to any of these remaining questions:

- Should the word "the" be capitalized after certain symbols, mainly the ampersand (&)? I haven't been able to find a clear answer to this, I've mostly left "the" without capitalization but for example, writing "KC & the Sunshine Band" looks a bit off to me, so I'm wondering if this is an exception case.
- How do you capitalize words before and after commas? For example, if there was a title called "Come on, Let's Travel", should the "on" be capitalized in this case, or would it be considered the last word of a phrase? And in another case, there's a track with the title of "You, on the Dance Floor". Should the "on" be capitalized after a comma, or is it still left uncapitalized?
- How do you capitalize hyphenated words? This has been an absolute mystery to me and I can't seem to find many rules on how to capitalize hypnehated words and I can't figure out how they work; sometimes it seems you need to capitalize both parts of the word and sometimes it isn't so.

Comment: Personally, I have nothing against users asking two or three questions as long as they are related to the same topic.But asking seven is stretching it.

Comment: If you want to know the guidance of the main style guides, [Title Case Converter](https://titlecaseconverter.com/) is an excellent reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is my rule of thumb, but rules can vary depending on the style manual you look at. If it's an article, a conjunction, or a preposition, they are never capitalized. Both parts of a hyphenated word should be capitalized. Verbs are always capitalized. In the example regarding "Come On, Let's Travel", I would capitalize that because "on" is idiomatic and not acting as a preposition.